# edit the text of a cell?

Tags: uiview, uitableview, edit

I have a UITableView, and want to let users edit the text of a cell. I want to popup a new UIView to let them enter some text in textfield, then dismiss the view and replace the cell's label text. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of an advanced move, Vikas. The programming of and user interaction with table view cells is tricky.  The reason is that the UI code is a bit tricky because of the scrollable view, and you have to be prepared for the table cells to move or change if the table data is reloaded.

Is there another way you can achieve the result you're looking for?  Could you design your table view so that when a cell is selected, you push a new view onto the navigation stack, and have UI components on that view that enable the user to edit the value?

This is the way that Apple does the **Settings** on iOS.  When you select a row, you are shown a new view that has appropriate editing or selection controls.

Answer (score -1):

You should use the textLabel property.

Comment: sorry i dont understand by that..? what kind of property?